# Limit of $\frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I am given the sequence

$$a_n=\frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}} $$

I have to show the limit for this sequence, and i think i have gotten the point of it, but i am struggling with how to show it.

What i did it first was to look at the sequence and determine that if i could show that the denominator is bigger than the numerator, then the sequence converges. I thought to myself that this is the case, but again i hit a brick wall when i had to write it down on paper in a mathematical way.

Next i tried dividing both the numerator and denominator with $2^n$ so i got:
$$\frac{1}{\big(\frac{3^{n+1}}{{2^n}}\big)}$$

Now i thought to myself that if i could show that this denominator is bigger than $n$ i would also have shown that the orignial $a_n$ converges to 0. But whatever i do i just cant seem to get it written down on paper in a proper mathematical way.

Comment: $a_n=(1/3)(2/3)^n$.

Comment: Hint: $a_{n}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\frac13\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac23\right)^n=0$$